# layoutIfNeeded affecting table view cells

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitableview

In my view controller I have a table view as a subview. When the keyboard disappears, I'm using `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` to animate the table view. This goes all well except for the table view cells.

The cells consists of a few labels, set up with auto layout. When the keyboard disappears, `layoutIfNeeded` is called for the table view but is affecting the cells as well. This results in weird behavior of the cells, having the labels "fly" to their position.

Is there a way to isolate `layoutIfNeeded` to the table view only without affecting it's subviews?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454792/1925852